# What were the nmes of Kidambi Aachan( Pranathirthaharam)'s parents? Was Kidambi Aachans father part of the brahmin group carrying water to temple

Tags: sri-vaishnava

I am told that a group of orthodox brahmins settled down near Kanchipuram to do kainkaryam at the Yatoktakari temple. They did this by collecting water (ambi) from the Vegavathi river in earthen pots (Ghatam) and bringing the water to the temple. I am told that that their duty labelled them as Ghatambi which later morphed to Kidambi.
The place where these brahmins settled was also called by the same name ie Kidambi
Pranathirthaharam came from this village.
He was in charge of Ramanujacharya's meals (Madapalli Aachan) an also an ardent disciple and simhasanadipathi